# Parallel Automation testing and thread safe variables

Tags: java, multithreading, automation, cucumber, browser-automation

I am running Automation tests in parallel. Different feature files are running on dedicated different browsers.

During this course of automation testing, several test users are created in each thread (5 feature has 5 browser).

Problem is 1 feature creates a user = dave+timestamp another created dave+new-timestamp. One feature file must use only user across its execution but it uses another user created by another feature (thread).

I think I need to make these users thread safe so that 1 user per feature(thread) can be used.

Actually, I am not a java developer only a QA doing automation testing, please suggest, guide how can I implement it.

This is how I am passing new user for registration form submission.
`endUser.doRegistration(getNewUser(userType));`

`getNewUser(userType)` = gives a new user if it's null, but it doesnt stop feature2 to create a user for it's use but that user in between the execution comes to feature1 also.

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt sound like a thread safety question, it sounds to me like your just trying to share data between scenarios? The answer to that largely depends on your application and whether or not your using an dependency injection... you didnt post your runner, your feature files, you stepdefs, or any information about your dependencies so help here will be relatively limited...

The simplest answer though would be to create a class that contained a user.
Somthing like this might work?

```
public class UserManager(){
private static User user;

public static User getUser(){
 if(user == null){
   //create your user here... Dave + Timestamp or whatever your user logic is
   user = new User();
  }
 return user;
 }
}
```

then each step def needs to contain a step like 
`Then a user is fetched'

Because the user object is static here, any stepdef that needs a user needs to simply call `UserManager.getUser()` to fetch the user, you'll get back the same user instance for each step.

Optionally you can define methods in your userManager class to reset the user etc. if need be between tests.

Now..  if your truly having issues with user data crossing your thread boundaries.. then you have two options.

1. Use thread local storage for storing user objects. Here is a guide: https://www.baeldung.com/java-threadlocal
2. Keep all users all in a big static map where your scenarios can fetch their own users by a test id, or browser type, etc.
   Both of those options are just variations on the theme above though..